# Jetpack compose Lazycolumn, wrong index when tapping on canvas item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I use a LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose and draw 2 canvas items (4 if screen is rotated) on each row. When i click on one canvas item, I want the canvas to be disabled (background red). I also draw a text item on each canvas to see the index number. This looks something like this (numRows = 64):

```
LazyColumn(
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)) {
items(numRows) { rowIndex ->
    ...
    CanvasRow(rowIndex,...)
}
```

}

In CanvasRow I draw the canvas items, a text with the current index and have click listeners like this:

```
    @Composable
fun CanvasRow(
    canvasIndex: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    disabled: Boolean)
{
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onTap = { mMainViewModel.onClicked(canvasIndex) },
                    onLongPress = {
                        mMainViewModel.onLongClicked(canvasIndex)
                    },
                )
            }
            .background(if (disabled) Color.Red else Color.Black),
        color = Color.Transparent
    ) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
               ...
            }

            drawPoints(
                points = points,
                color = Color.White,
                strokeWidth = 2.0f,
                pointMode = PointMode.Polygon
            )

            drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
                val text = (canvasIndex + 1).toString()
                val fontSize = 12.sp
                val textColor = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.75f)

                val textX = 20f
                val textY = fontSize.toPx() + 10f
                canvas.nativeCanvas.drawText(text, textX, textY, textPaint)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when my ViewModel data changes, the ui is recomposed and the canvas items are drawn and all the text items have the correct index. When I scroll down or up, everything works and looks good. Only thing is, when I click on an canvas item after scrolled down or up, the wrong index is passed to my Viewmodel. I know, that there is a key identifier in LazyColumn, but I don´t know how to use this in this case correctly, because I don´t get the items from my Viewmodel directly, I draw periodically some data on the canvas items when my data in my Viewmodel changes.
How can I solve this problem that my Viewmodel gets the incorrect item index when I click on a canvas after scrolling down or up in LazyColumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I used an alpha version of Compose which caused all the problems! After changing the version to a stable Compose version, everything works as expected. Never thought, that this would be such a problem!